# Linux, bash, найти регулярное выражение в файле

Tags: linux, bash

Имеется файл, содержимое которого является логом работы сторонней программы, файл может быть большим, сотни строк. Необходимо распарсить файл, и если в нем имеется регулярное выражение, например `'some error occured'`, то выйти с кодом 1.

Думаю сделать так- сначала прочитать файл в переменную: `my_log=$(cat log_file.log)` а затем как то определить, есть ли в значении переменной `my_log` данное регулярное выражение. Но не понимаю как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cat log_file.log|grep -c 'some error occured'

Comment: Постарайтесь давать более развёрнутые ответы, иначе ответы могут удаляться. А также почитайте тут: [/help/how-to-answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @PetLinux Вообще ответ должен работать, в теории)

Comment: И зачем тут cat? grep прекрасно сам умеет читать файлы, передаваемые в аргументах

Comment: Не вопрос : grep -c 'some error occured'  log_file.log

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "${2}" ]]; then
    echo "Usage: ${0} pattern file"
    exit 2
fi

# Ищем шаблон (первый аргумент скрипта) в файле (второй аргумент):
grep -e "${1}" "${2}" 2>&1 > /dev/null
# В переменной $? будет 0 если шаблон найден  и 1 если нет.

# Но нам нужно инвертировать (вернуть 1 если найден, 0 если нет), поэтому:
RC=$(( "${?}" ^ 1 ))

# Готово:
# echo "${RC}"
exit "${RC}"
```

Comment: Можно одной строчкой `if grep -q "$1" "$2" ; then false; else true; fi`  (grep сам ругнется на неверные аргументы)

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно одного `grep`:

```
grep -q 'some error occured' $file_name && exit 1
```